# Foundry user attribute not changing in UI after API update

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have changed an attribute of a user using Foundry's `providerId` APIs. When I query by using the APIs, I get the new attributes but the Foundry UI is still displaying the old attribute. Is this a kind of caching? Or is there an action I should take to trigger this change to take action?

Answer (score 0):

You need the user to login to foundry after you make the provider change. The actual user login flow from the new provider updates the user.